# How To create Different Validation Rules in store and updata, in Form Request Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-formrequest

using the request form in laravel, so I want to make a different validation during store and update, when the store method is run the photo field is required, but in update I don't want to provide any validation on the photo field, can someone help me?

This is My Validation Rules

```
class GalleryRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'judul'=>'required|max:255',
            'photo'=>'sometimes|required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,gif,tif,svg|max:6000',
        ];
    }
}
```

In essence I just want to make a different validation between store and update in laravel using form request

Comment: you can check what the HTTP method of the request is and decide what set of rules to use based on that

Answer (score 0):

i assume  id is there at both time when insert/update is made (id=0 when insert and >0 when update),so based on it you can do something like this inside rule function:

```
public function rules()
{
    if($this->inputs['id']<=0)
    {
            return [
               'judul'=>'required|max:255',
          'photo'=>'sometimes|required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,gif,tif,svg|max:6000',
             ];
    }else{
            return [
               'judul'=>'required|max:255'];
      }
}
```